# Appending using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

Okay, this is a really long post.  I have a multiple DOM tree structure that I need to traverse through in order to insert an image.  For the record, the image passes into PARAM fine.  What I don't understand is why it's not posting.  So, here is the code I am currently using.

```
function validateImage(event) {
    var $input = $(this);
    var width = 75;
    var height = $input.closest('.logo-block').length > 0 ? 35: 75;
    $input.animate({
        'backgroundColor': '#999'
    },
    250);
    $.get('/meta/thumbnail/' + $input.val() + '/' + height + '/' + width + '/',
    function(result) {
        $input.stop();
        if (result != 'No Image Available') {
            $input.css('background-color', '#55FF00');
            var $block = $input.closest('div.thumb-image');
            if ($block.closest('.center-callout-info').length > 0) {
                // in center column, add image.
                $input.val('');
                $('<div class="thumb">' + result + '</div>').appendTo($block.closest('.image-container').not($block.closest('.more-images .image-container'))).find('img').addClass('selected');
            $('.center-callout-info .block img.meta-thumb').click(bindImageSelection);
            }
        } else {
            $input.css('background-color', '#FF0000');
            $input.val('');
        }
        $input.animate({
            backgroundColor: '#FCFCFD'
        },
        2000);
    });
}
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<fieldset class="collapsible collapsed">
    <legend class="collapse"><a href="#">Image Management</a></legend>
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper"><input type="button" value="Save Images" id="saveForm" class="submitButton" name="save" />
        <div class="center-callout-info">
            <div class="callout-images">
                <div class="high-res block active-tab" id="46051">
                    <div class = "image-container">
                        <div class="thumb-image thumb selected" id="AVE_BOX_TOPS_EDUCATION_4C">
                        <img class="meta-thumb" height="" src="/thumbs/AVE_Box_Tops_Education_4C.png" title="AVE_BOX_TOPS_EDUCATION_4C" /></div>
                    <div class="thumb-image thumb selected" id="FEL_BANKERS_BOX_BLK">
                        <img class="meta-thumb" height="" src="/thumbs/FEL_BANKERS_BOX_BLK.png" title="FEL_BANKERS_BOX_BLK" /></div>
                    <div class="thumb-image thumb selected" id="FEL_BB_FOLDER_RAILS_BLK">
                        <img class="meta-thumb" height="" src="/thumbs/FEL_BB_Folder_Rails_BLK.png" title="FEL_BB_FOLDER_RAILS_BLK" /></div>
                    <div class="thumb-image thumb selected" id="FEL_SFI_BLK">
                        <img class="meta-thumb" height="" src="No Image Available" title="FEL_SFI_BLK" /></div>
                    <form action="/node/46051/edit"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="skuimage-get-more-form">

                        <div><div class="form-item" id="edit-new-high-res-wrapper">
                        <label for="edit-new-high-res">New: </label>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="128" name="new_high_res" id="edit-new-high-res" size="15" value="AVE_AVERY_BLK" class="form-text new-button" />
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-de9c77d3f4d32257a52dc609e6697769" value="form-de9c77d3f4d32257a52dc609e6697769"  />
                        <input type="hidden" name="form_token" id="edit-skuimage-get-more-form-form-token" value="f7bb86ba8678fa2fb5b911f1df819bec"  />
                        <input type="hidden" name="form_id" id="edit-skuimage-get-more-form" value="skuimage_get_more_form"  />

                        </div></form>
                        </div></div></div></div></div></fieldset>
```

Now, I would like the `<IMG>` to appear with the other `<IMG>`'s, which are located inside of the div with class `image-container`.

I think I have everything in the message here.  Any help would be great.

EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT

Here is the answer:

Alright, here is what the answer was.  Above you will see the following line of code:

```
var $block = $input.closest('div.thumb-image');
```

However, after traversing up the DOM Tree, I found out that I needed to set this to be the actual place I wanted to PUT the image.  So, `var $block` actually is the following:

```
var $block = $input.closest('.image-container');
```

After that, I had to change the place where it put the image as well.

```
$('<div class="thumb">' + result + '</div>').appendTo($block).find('img').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: No, no errors.  It's just not posting to the page.

Comment: @webdevsoup If you answer your own question, please post the answer below and let the community help you evaluate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

6 years later, I'll answer my own question. LOL

Alright, here is what the answer was. Above you will see the following line of code:

```
var $block = $input.closest('div.thumb-image');
```

However, after traversing up the DOM Tree, I found out that I needed to set this to be the actual place I wanted to PUT the image. So, var $block actually is the following:

```
var $block = $input.closest('.image-container');
```

After that, I had to change the place where it put the image as well.

```
$('<div class="thumb">' + result + '</div>').appendTo($block).find('img').addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear about your post. But if have understood a bit, it is about sending image and getting a response from the backend of the application.
I am sorry if I got it wrong, but if I am right. Then here is my answer --

You cannot upload file using ajax. That is you cannot send files in functions like $.ajax(), $.get(), $.post(), etc. as data.